# Device Compatibility with Google Pixel 6 and latest Samsung Galaxy models in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Our Cordova apps are not showing in the Play Store for the latest Google Pixel and Samsung Galaxy phones.   The store says the application is not compatible with these devices.   Any recommendations for the SDK settings to support these devices?  Has anyone been successful publishing apps that support these newer devices?  (Google Pixel 3+)

Comment: I believe you need to support  SDK 30 +, what target are you targetting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @Eric  -- if you have time -- could you contact me at droussain@nclarity.com as we're looking for help to solve this issue asap.  Thanks.